# How do I shut down my OS with Java

Tags: java

How do I shut down my OS with Java?

Comment: you probably need to post what you've done so far and more details about your OS

Comment: Does the method of shutting down need to be OS independent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from : [a blog](http://deepakjha.wordpress.com/2007/09/17/did-u-know-that-u-can-shutdown-someones-machinewindows-using-java/)

```
package com.deepak.entertainment;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class Deepak {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
  Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
  try {
   Process process = runtime.exec(”C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe”);
   OutputStream os = process.getOutputStream();
   os.write(”shutdown -s -f -t 90 \n\r”.getBytes());
   os.close();
   process.waitFor();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

}
```

Comment: Yes, just read the code and you can update what goes in the runtime.exec so that it can be a Linux command or any other OS command.. Linux "shutdown -h now" or "init 0" ..

Answer (score 5):

I believe that since Java is OS independent there is no direct way to do it, other than invoking something from the underlying OS.

Comment: Java could provide an OS independent method for shutting down the machine.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly shut OS with Java, but you can execute a shell script or native program e.g `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("shutdown")`. Or you can write `JNI` hook into native system

Answer (score 1):

You can execute [shutdown](http://www.computerhope.com/shutdown.htm) DOS command on XP and higher

Answer (score 1):

```
// May need to change for a Swing or SWT application.
System.out.println ("Please shut down your OS now. I'll wait...");
boolean forever = true;
while (forever) {}
```

:-)